# Split data.frame by value

Tags: r, split, dataframe

how can I split the following data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", 1, 2, 3, "a", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "a", 1, 2), var2 = 1:14)
```

into lists of / groups of

```
a 1
1 2
2 3
3 4

a 5
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
6 11

a 12
1 13
2 14
```

So basically, value "a" in column 1 is the tag / identifier I want to split the data frame on. I know about the split function but that means I have to add another column and since, as can be seen from my example, the size of the groups can vary I do not know how to automatically create such a dummy column to fit my needs.

Any ideas on that?

Cheers,

Sven

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could find which values of the indexing vector equal "a", then create a grouping variable based on that and then use split.

```
df[,1] == "a"
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[13] FALSE FALSE
cumsum(df[,1] == "a")
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
split(df, cumsum(df[,1] == "a"))
#$`1`
#  var1 var2
#1    a    1
#2    1    2
#3    2    3
#4    3    4
#
#$`2`
#   var1 var2
#5     a    5
#6     1    6
#7     2    7
#8     3    8
#9     4    9
#10    5   10
#11    6   11
#
#$`3`
#   var1 var2
#12    a   12
#13    1   13
#14    2   14
```

Comment: This looks suspiciously like something I'd suggest.  Are you my clone?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Do clones get a proportion of your reputation?  If so then yes.

Comment: I already gave you 10, what more do you want?  Gosh, clones are needy... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a loop that loops through the entire first column of the data frame and saves the positions of non-numeric characters in a vector.  Thus, you'd have something like:

```
data <- df$var1 #this gives you a vector of the values you'll sort through

positions <- c()

for (i in seq(1:length(data))){
    if (is.numeric(data[i]) == TRUE) {
        #nothing
    }
    else positions <- append(positions, i) #saves the positions of the non-numeric characters
}
```

With those positions, you shouldn't have a problem accessing splitting up the data frame from there.  It's just a matter of using sequences between the values in the position vector.

Comment: thanks for your code snippet as well. The problem with that solution is that the other values which are not "a" can also be text and are not always numbers. Maybe my example wasn't well designed enough. However, also good to know that solution. thanks! :)

Comment: If the goal is to find the positions you don't need a loop. You could do something like `which(df$var1=="a")`. Try to avoid loops as your first choice when using R.

Comment: @Roland I'm used to programming in python, so that's the reason I tend to use loops.  I find a solid knowledge of how to use loops eliminates the need to memorize tons of built-in functions, but how did you get a feel for all of these functions?  There's probably a lot of instances where I personally could be using these functions, but don't know about them.

Comment: Quite often loops are the least efficient way to achieve something in R (by orders of magnitude). That gets you motivated to search for (vectorized) functions.