# Splitting a data frame in R - Missing block column

Tags: r, split, dataframe

This is my first time asking something till now i could find what i was looking for from other topics. I am fairly new to R so it may be easy to do it. Well i have a data frame like this

```
col1  col2  col3
start   NA    NA
    1    
    2
    3
  ...
  126
start   NA    NA
    1
    2
  ...
  158
```

I want to split this data frame every time it finds the variable "start" in the first column. In the example above i want to take 2 data frames with 126 and 158 lines each. It seems that split() function could do the trick but i dont have a block column like the example below. Well if i could create this column problem is solved like this i think split(test.frame,test.frame$block == 1).

```
col1  col2  col3  block
start   NA    NA      1
    1                 1
    2                 1
    3                 1
  ...
  126                 1
start   NA    NA      2
    1                 2
    2                 2
  ...
  158                 2
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance all!

Comment: Found my answer here, cumsum is what i was looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402088/split-data-frame-by-value?rq=1